# How to stop Emacs from interpreting a file name with `@` as an email address

Tags: helm, find-file

If I try to open a file whose filename is `~/A/b/C@d.yaml`, Emacs will interpret that I want to send an email to the address `C@d.yaml`, and in the minibuffer I have `mailto:C@d.yaml`.

What could I do so that I can keep `@` in the filename?

I use `helm-find-file` if that matters.

Comment: Please provide a recipe to reproduce what you see, starting from `emacs -Q`. If `helm-find-file` is not required for the recipe then leave it out (and remove the `helm` tag in that case. IOW, please provide a fairly minimal recipe. With just `emacs -Q` I don't see that when using `C-x C-f` (`find-file`).

Comment: Does this happen when you launch emacs without your init file (emacs -Q)?  If not, recursively bisect your init file (comment out successive halves until you isolate the problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a feature of `helm-find-files`, when your point is on URL, such as "http://example.com" and "foo@example.com", `helm-find-files` guesses you want to "open" these link. To avoid this, you can move your point from "C@d.yaml" to "~/A/b/", then it will thinks it's a file path at point.

```
~/A/b/C@d.yaml
++++++--------
```

If you don't need or want this feature at all, you can turn off via `helm-ff-guess-ffap-urls`, i.e.,

```
(setq helm-ff-guess-ffap-urls nil)
```

> helm-ff-guess-ffap-urls is a variable defined in ‘helm-files.el’.
>   Its value is t
>
> Documentation:
>   Use ffap to guess local urls at point in
>   ‘helm-find-files’. This doesn’t disable guessing filenames at point,
>   see ‘helm-ff-guess-ffap-filenames’ for this.
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is exactly what i am looking for.